# IPython / Jupyter ... return a bad interpreter error

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have a problem in my installation of python on my Mac. I've recently removed my 3.6 version of python to install with homebrew the 3.7 version.

At this step all is good, when I install different packages that's works.

```
pip3 install ipython jupyter
```

The prompt return successfully operations. But... Is there I don't understand.

When I put the command line :

```
ipython
```

or

```
ipython3
```

or

```
jupyter
```

The prompt return :

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/ipython3: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

In my bash_profile I inserted :

```
export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3"
```

And this pointed to the 3.7 version of python and this dependencies.

Could someone help me please ?

Best,

Chris

Comment: Looks like pip is not aware of python upgrade, try reinstalling pip3

Comment: pip as the latest version, I can resolved the problem by passing by a virtual environnement but it doesn't work in brut env.